# aws glue create-crawler fails on Configuration settings

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, glue-crawler

When running the following

```
aws glue create-crawler --debug --cli-input-json '{
  "Name": "crawler",
  "Role": "arn:...",
  "DatabaseName": "db",
  "Description": "table crawler",
  "Targets": { 
  "CatalogTargets": [{
                      "DatabaseName": "db",
                      "Tables": ["tab"]
                    }]
  },
  "SchemaChangePolicy": {
      "UpdateBehavior": "LOG",
      "DeleteBehavior": "LOG"
  },
  "RecrawlPolicy": {
    "RecrawlBehavior": "CRAWL_EVERYTHING"
  },
    "Configuration": {
           "Version": 1.0,
           "CrawlerOutput": {
             "Partitions": { "AddOrUpdateBehavior": "InheritFromTable" }
           },
           "Grouping": { "TableGroupingPolicy": "CombineCompatibleSchemas" }
         },
  "Schedule": "Cron(1 * * * ? *)"
}'
```

It fails on

```
Parameter validation failed:
Invalid type for parameter Configuration, value: {'Version': 1.0, 'CrawlerOutput': {'Partitions': {'AddOrUpdateBehavior': 'InheritFromTable'}}, 'Grouping': {'TableGroupingPolicy': 'CombineCompatibleSchemas'}}, type: <class 'dict'>, valid types: <class 'str'>
```

I'm getting the format from [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/crawler-configuration.html#crawler-configure-changes-api) and if I remove `Configuration` it works. I tried all kind of quoting options to make this dictionary into one string but everything fails. Would love some help spotting the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to move the configuration to an argument in that command

```
aws glue create-crawler --configuration '{
           "Version": 1.0,
           "CrawlerOutput": {
             "Partitions": { "AddOrUpdateBehavior": "InheritFromTable" }
           },
           "Grouping": { "TableGroupingPolicy": "CombineCompatibleSchemas" }
         }' --debug --cli-input-json '{
  "Name": "crawler",
  "Role": "arn:...",
  "DatabaseName": "db",
  "Description": "table crawler",
  "Targets": { 
  "CatalogTargets": [{
                      "DatabaseName": "db",
                      "Tables": ["tab"]
                    }]
  },
  "SchemaChangePolicy": {
      "UpdateBehavior": "LOG",
      "DeleteBehavior": "LOG"
  },
  "RecrawlPolicy": {
    "RecrawlBehavior": "CRAWL_EVERYTHING"
  },
  "Schedule": "Cron(1 * * * ? *)"
}'
```